# createdAt updatedAt aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

In mongoose, there's the `timestamp: true` option to a schema, which auto-populates a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` for any model item added.

Is there something similar in Aqueduct?

If not, how do I manually do so?

I currently tried this, which is failing, as usual:

```
  @Operation.post()
  Future<Response> createICD(@Bind.body() ICD body) async {
    body.createdAt = DateTime.now();
    final query = Query<ICD>(context)..values = body;
    final insertICD = await query.insert();

    return Response.ok({'state': true, 'data': insertICD});
  }
```

Error from the above approach is:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'ICD'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing when you send the response; you need to call `asMap()` on `insertICD`. The response body object you are providing is a standard Dart map - it doesn't have any special encoding behavior, so it doesn't know how to encode a complex type like `ManagedObject`. Invoke `asMap()`  on the managed object to convert it to a standard Dart map:

```
@Operation.post()
Future<Response> createICD(@Bind.body() ICD body) async {
  body.createdAt = DateTime.now();
  final query = Query<ICD>(context)..values = body;
  final insertICD = await query.insert();

  return Response.ok({'state': true, 'data': insertICD.asMap()});
}
```

Also, see http://aqueduct.io/docs/db/validations/#update-and-insert-callbacks for setting timestamps at create/update events.